# How to convert raw PHP Join Query into Magento Join Query

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, best-practice, join

How to convert raw php `LEFT JOIN` query in to magento query?
What is Magentos syntax for?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT fieldsmanager_orders.value,sales_flat_order_address.entity_id
FROM fieldsmanager_orders
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address ON fieldsmanager_orders.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.entity_id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your parent collection model like

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('fieldsmanager/orders')->getCollection();
```

**Note:** Make sure your namespace/entity is correct.

Then from the main collection you can join the `sales_flat_order_address` table.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('sales_flat_order_address'=>$collection->getTable('sales/order_address')),
    'main_table.entity_id=sales_flat_order_address.entity_id,
    array('*')
);
```

**Parameters description**

Here in first parameter you pass the table you want to join with.You can use an array of the format `array('alias' => 'namespace/entity')`

In second parameter you add your condition to join with.

and in third one you pass the columns you want from join. `"*"` resembles for all columns. If you want specific column you can pass in that array.

Comment: i have two table fieldsmanager_orders, and sales_flat_order_address

Comment: Yes so this will  work as above. You can load your main table collection ( fieldsmanager_orders) then you can join it with sales_flat_order_address table as shown above.